# Sublime Text 3 Literal Dollar Sign with Stata

Tags: sublimetext3, stata

I started using Sublime Text 3 for Stata with Improved Stata Editor for MacOS. I need to use `$` (literal dollar sign) to call global variables, but whenever I try to type in `$ (shift+4) ${}` with a line break between two parentheses.

I found some posts about snippets, but I am not sure how to go about this. May I get some help on this?

Comment: Your post isn't quite complete. Can you please finish what you were talking about in the first paragraph?

Comment: Are you saying you want `$` to turn into `${\n}` or that it's doing that and you don't want it to?

Comment: @OdatNurd based on the [code](https://github.com/zizhongyan/StataImproved/blob/master/StataImproved.py#L21-L34) in the repo, if you type in `$`, regardless of the context, it replaces it with `${\n}`. If text is selected, it wraps the selected text. Kinda lousy design. And, the author doesn't appear to have interacted with the repo or responded to issues since last May.

Comment: @MattDMo In that case, overriding [this key binding](https://github.com/zizhongyan/StataImproved/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap#L37-L41) will stop it from doing that. The easiest thing would probably be a similar binding that uses `insert` to insert a `$` and override that command.

Comment: @OdatNurd sounds good. Feel free to write up an answer...

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. I am just not sure how to fix this... Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I tried typing stuff like {"keys": ["insert"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "$"}}

Comment: This worked! {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+4"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\\$"}}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.